# Real use case for Bootstrap column ordering (push, pull)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the Bootstrap 3 documentation they give the following example of using `push` and `pull` classes to change column ordering (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

I understand how this works but why would you not just write the order in which you want them to appear in your HTML, like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"> ... </div>
</div>
```

I can't see any possible use case for the example they give, because whether the **order** is `col-md-3, col-md-9`, or `col-md-9, col-md-3` you're still not going to gain any more or less width on any device - they still add up to 12. Therefore why not just define it in the HTML in the correct order?

I understand how the classes work technically. But I don't understand what the use case of them could possibly be since they don't appear to do anything you cannot do already by defining things in the order you want? Essentially you can't gain any more or less viewport width on a given device, so where would you ever want to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column ordering classes allow us to change the order of our grid system based on different browser sizes. This means that on a large screen, you can have a different grid than on a mobile screen.

You can check this for example,
https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Comment: The link you posted is very useful but I still don't fully understand why you'd use it. If `B` is more important (content wise) than `A` then surely you'd still just define it as `B, A, C`. The thing this will never solve is giving you more *width* (because that's impossible) so I don't see why presenting columns in that way is advantageous. It would help to see a website where the *content* order changes in a way with a perceivable benefit to the user.

Comment: What if priorities changes with screen size? If I want items sorted by A, B, C  in big screens and item B has more priority in mobile and I want B, A, C in the mobile phone then what?

At that time bootstrap pull/push is very useful I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> why would you not just write the order in which you want them to
>   appear in your HTML

It's because when we write markup we're supposed to think of its semantics too.

For example you have a page which has a sidebar on the left side, and an article on the right side. In your markup hierarchy the article should comes before the sidebar because the article is the main page content.

But then if you `float` them `left`, the article will be on the left side and sidebar will be on the right side, which is the opposite of what you want to achieve. So to fix this you will use `push` and `pull` classes, you get the idea.

This is just an example. Of course other options are available to achieve the same result such as `float` them `right`, or place the sidebar markup before article but wrap it with `<aside>` element.